# Using Wagtail CMS Collections to Manage Permissions to Custom Settings

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I am building an app for an Association with many Chapters.  I setup the default `site (localhost)` for the Association corporate office, and a Chapter `Site (denver.localhost)` with a default landing page - they have dozens of other chapters that will be setup similar to this.

I went into `Collections` and setup a collection called Denver and then in Groups, setup a custom group called Denver as well.  This allows me to setup group permissions for the Denver chapter to only have access to the Denver landing page root directory, Denver images and Denver Documents.  These permissions are all controlled by `Collections`.

I would like to setup custom snippets or models with Chapter specific information such as address, phone, social links, etc.. but cannot figure out how to create them in a way that will allow me to assign them to their specific collection, thus allowing the chapter users to modify their data only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nearly nothing documented regarding Collections, except that they were introduced in 1.4.4.

Taken from the [wagtail sources](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py#L1854):

> A location in which resources such as images and documents can be grouped

I'm afraid that Collections currently only support Documents and Images properly.